# javascript function errors when trying to return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

My Goal:  I am writing a widget for a job which will populate a div with contents.  I dont even get to execute the information as get the error:
       Uncaught Syntax Error:  Unexpected Token Return

I wrote an object which executes this function as follows:

```
function TreeView(){
    this.rebuild = contructRoot();
}

function constructRoot(){
    var resultant = ajax_Request();
    var content = $(resultant);

    var root = $("<div>");
    var root_nodes = ajax_Request("/startTreeAJAX");
    root_nodes.split("|");
    root.html(
        $("<div>").html(
            $("<ul>").append($('<li>').html(root_nodes[0])).append($("<li>").html(root_nodes[1]))
        )
    );
    root.find("li").click(function(){
        clickExpand(this);
    });

    return root.html();
}
```

I am trying to essentially return the elements contents.

Comment: what does `ajax_Request()` do? Is it asynchronous in nature?

Comment: Where is the closing curly brace of constructRoot function?

Comment: it does an ajax request to a webservice, which is dependant on the passed in function

Comment: your `return` statement needs a `}` after it

Comment: That's a problem then. Your code won't wait for `ajax_Request()` to finish processing since it AJAX calls are asynchronous.

Comment: There are many problems with this code. For example, the nested `.html()` calls don't make sense since they don't *return* any HTML markup.

Comment: the return one is there in my code, I was just being quick.

Comment: `$('<li>').html(root_nodes[0]) + $("<li>").html(root_nodes[1])`  This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: html() returns markup or sets its contents with the input elements.  WIth that said, my code SHOULD end up building something like <div><div><ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul</ul></div></div> and then return everything inside the first div

Comment: ahhh ok.  Maybe i should form it differently

Comment: @Fallenreaper: No, it doesn't work that way. When setting HTML, it returns a jQuery object.

Comment: You are correct.  It returns the jquery object, which i can reference.

Comment: ...since you're creating new DOM Elements, you should use `.append()`, and do two separate appends for the innermost elements.

Comment: @amnotiam: You can pass jQuery objects to `.html`.

Comment: I had adjusted it to append to make it look nicer and do more of what i was wanting

Comment: @Fallenreaper: You keep changing the code in the question.  What is your question?

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Why are you adding click events to `root.find("li")` if you are never adding them to the DOM.  Those events *won't* appear when you return `root.html()`.

Comment: @Rocket I was thinking it would return the contents in a string.  Does it not?  I was going to on the other side of the return, append to DOM.  I was just thinking to set up everything on this side, then pass it all back

Comment: @Fallenreaper: `.html` will return the contents as a string, yes.  It won't include the `click` events you've bound.  If you're gonna append it to the DOM, just return the jQuery element itself instead.  `return root;`

Comment: @Rocket: *"You can pass jQuery objects to .html"* Ah, that's right. More unintuitive API from jQuery.

Comment: Well, then what i will do is pass in a reference to the DOM and insert/apply it there. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closing `)` of the `.click()` is missing, and don't forget to close your function definition with `}` after the `return`.  When you see a syntax error like an unexpected token, start looking to the things immediately before it to find your problem...

```
  root.find("li").click(function(){ 
     clickExpand(this);
  }); // <----

  return root.html();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your curly braces and parenthesis.  You're missing a few of them.

```
root.find("li").click(function () {
    clickExpand(this);
});  // <-- you're missing the `)` here
```

```
    return root.html();
} // <-- You're missing the `}` here
```

**UPDATE**: As others have stated, there are other issues with this code.

```
root_nodes.split("|");
```

This doesn't do anything.  You need to set `root_nodes` to that.

```
root_nodes = root_nodes.split("|");
```

```
var c = $('<li>').html(root_nodes[0]) + $("<li>").html(root_nodes[1]);
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  The `+` will concatenate strings, thus returning:

```
"[object Object][object Object]"
```

`.append` can accept a jQuery object (or an array), so I suggest doing this:

```
var c = [$('<li>').html(root_nodes[0]), $("<li>").html(root_nodes[1])];
root.html($("<div>").html($("<ul>").append(c)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's split() method returns an array. In your code above, you need to receive and store that array.

```
root_nodes = root_nodes.split("|")
```